# Getting all keys in a dict that overlap with other keys in the same dict

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, dictionary, python-itertools

I have a list comprehension that looks like this:

```
cart = [ ((p,pp),(q,qq)) for ((p,pp),(q,qq))\
         in itertools.product(C.items(), repeat=2)\
         if p[1:] == q[:-1] ]
```

`C` is a dict with keys that are tuples of arbitrary integers . All the tuples have the same length. Worst case is that all the combinations should be included in the new list. This can happen quite frequently.

As an example, I have a dictionary like this:

```
C = { (0,1):'b',
      (2,0):'c',
      (0,0):'d' }
```

And I want the the result to be:

```
cart = [ (((2, 0), 'c'), ((0, 1), 'b'))
         (((2, 0), 'c'), ((0, 0), 'd'))
         (((0, 0), 'd'), ((0, 1), 'b'))
         (((0, 0), 'd'), ((0, 0), 'd')) ]
```

So, by overlap I am referring to, for instance, that the tuples `(1,2,3,4)` and `(2,3,4,5)` have the overlapping section (2,3,4). The overlapping sections must be on the "edges" of the tuples. I only want overlaps that have length one shorter than the tuple length. Thus `(1,2,3,4)` does not overlap with `(3,4,5,6)`. Also note that when removing the first or last element of a tuple we might end up with non-distinct tuples, all of which must be compared to all the other elements. **This last point was not emphasized in my first example.**

The better part of my codes execution time is spent in this list comprehension. I always need all elements of `cart` so there appears to be no speedup when using a generator instead.

My question is: Is there a faster way of doing this?

A thought I had was that I could try to create two new dictionaries like this:

```
aa = defaultdict(list)
bb = defaultdict(list)
[aa[p[1:]].append(p) for p in C.keys()]
[bb[p[:-1]].append(p) for p in C.keys()]
```

And somehow merge all combinations of elements of the list in `aa[i]` with the list in `bb[i]` for all `i`, but I can not seem to wrap my head around this idea either.

**Update**

Both the solution added by tobias_k and shx2 have better complexity than my original code (as far as I can tell). My code is O(n^2) whereas the two other solutions are O(n). For my problem size and composition however, all three solutions seem to run at more or less the same time. I suppose this has to do with a combination of overhead associated with function calls, as well as the nature of the data I am working with. In particular the number of different keys, as well as the actual composition of the keys, seem to have a large impact. The latter I know because the code runs much slower for completely random keys. I have accepted tobias_k's answer because his code is the easiest to follow. However, i would still greatly welcome other suggestions on how to perform this task.

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for their side effects. Use a normal for loop instead, there is a cost to build a list you are discarding again.

Comment: the first version of my code had a regular for loop with a `continue` if `p[1:] != q[0:lvl]`. That was (to my surprise) slower than the code I have provided in my question.

Comment: can you explain more clearly what the code is meant to do?  perhaps by showing some simple examples?  and what is the "*2" needed for?  in particular, you seem to be mixing keys and values as if they are the same type of thing, yet say nothing about values.

Comment: I have updated the question. `product(*[C.items()]*2)` is the same as writing `product(C.items(),C.items())`, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean by "overlap". And what exactly is `lvl`? If it is the length of the tuples `p` and `q`, i.e. `2`, won't `q[0:lvl]` be just `q`? Also, given the `cart` list comprehension and your example dict I can not reproduce your results. If `lvl` is `2` the result is empty and if `lvl` is `1` I get one additional element in the `cart` list.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the question again. The actual code is rather more complex than this, so it is a bit challenging to strip it down correctly. Sorry about the confusion. By overlap I am referring to, for instance, that the tuples `(1,2,3,4)` and `(2,3,4,5)` have the overlapping section `(2,3,4)`. The overlapping sections must be on the "edges" of the tuples.

Comment: @shall.be.lifted Could you add this bit about the overlap to your question? Also, note that the length of the tuples should be `lvl+1`, not `lvl-1`. (Or, just write `q[:-1]`, which has the same effect and is much clearer.)

Comment: Done. There was a reason for using lvl on the original code. As you point out it makes little sense here.

Comment: Do you need the result to be sorted? What is `len(p)` compared to `len(C.items())`?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i do not need the result to be sorted. `len(p)` is around 20-40 and `len(C.items())` can be 2000 - 10000. depending on how fast i can get this i might want a larger `p` which in turn will result in a larger `C` (because of other parts of the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually on the right track, using the dictionaries to store all the prefixes to the keys. However, keep in mind that (as far as I understand the question) two keys can also overlap if the overlap is *less than* `len-1`, e.g. the keys `(1,2,3,4)` and `(3,4,5,6)` would overlap, too. Thus we have to create a map holding *all* the prefixes of the keys. (If I am mistaken about this, just drop the two inner `for` loops.) Once we have this map, we can iterate over all the keys a second time, and check whether for any of their suffixes there are matching keys in the `prefixes` map. (*Update:* Since keys can overlap w.r.t. more than one prefix/suffix, we store the overlapping pairs in a set.)

```
def get_overlap(keys):
    # create map: prefix -> set(keys with that prefix)
    prefixes = defaultdict(set)
    for key in keys:
        for prefix in [key[:i] for i in range(len(key))]:
            prefixes[prefix].add(key)
    # get keys with matching prefixes for all suffixes
    overlap = set()
    for key in keys:
        for suffix in [key[i:] for i in range(len(key))]:
            overlap.update([(key, other) for other in prefixes[suffix]
                                                      if other != key])
    return overlap
```

(Note that, for simplicity, I only care about the keys in the dictionary, not the values. Extending this to return the values, too, or doing this as a postprocessing step, should be trivial.)

Overall running time should be only `2*n*k`, `n` being the number of keys and `k` the length of the keys. Space complexity (the size of the `prefixes` map) should be between `n*k` and `n^2*k`, if there are very many keys with the same prefixes.

**Note:** The above answer is for the more general case that the overlapping region can have *any* length. For the simpler case that you consider only overlaps one shorter than the original tuple, the following should suffice and yield the results described in your examples:

```
def get_overlap_simple(keys):
    prefixes = defaultdict(list)
    for key in keys:
        prefixes[key[:-1]].append(key)
    return [(key, other) for key in keys for other in prefixes[key[1:]]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have tried to be more precise in my definition of overlap in the main question. I will be testing the code when I have the time, and I will select an answer and update my question as soon as I can.

Comment: I'm sorry about this, but it turns out that I didn't think my example through enough. I have updated the question with a new example dict.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of preprocessing the data into a dict was a good one.  Here goes:

```
from itertools import groupby
C = { (0,1): 'b', (2,0): 'c', (0,0): 'd' }

def my_groupby(seq, key):
    """
     >>> group_by(range(10), lambda x: 'mod=%d' % (x % 3))
     {'mod=2': [2, 5, 8], 'mod=0': [0, 3, 6, 9], 'mod=1': [1, 4, 7]}
    """
    groups = dict()
    for x in seq:
        y = key(x)
        groups.setdefault(y, []).append(x)
    return groups

def get_overlapping_items(C):
    prefixes = my_groupby(C.iteritems(), key = lambda (k,v): k[:-1])
    for k1, v1 in C.iteritems():
        prefix = k1[1:]
        for k2, v2 in prefixes.get(prefix, []):
            yield (k1, v1), (k2, v2)

for x in get_overlapping_items(C):
    print x     

(((2, 0), 'c'), ((0, 1), 'b'))
(((2, 0), 'c'), ((0, 0), 'd'))
(((0, 0), 'd'), ((0, 1), 'b'))
(((0, 0), 'd'), ((0, 0), 'd'))
```

And by the way, instead of:

```
itertools.product(*[C.items()]*2)
```

do:

```
itertools.product(C.items(), repeat=2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `repeat=2`. Your code looks very promising. I will select an answer when I have played around with this a little more.

Comment: This answer worked for my first example. However, I realized that what the list comprehension in my code does is not quite the same. I have updated the question. Again.

Comment: ok, I updated my answer to use a slightly different group-by semantics.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work very nice. (That is, it passes all my unit tests) However it runs at almost the exact same speed as my original code.

Comment: how big is your data structure, and how big do you expect the result to be, roughly?

Comment: At the moment `C` has around 2000 - 10000 elements in the worst case. The tuple keys have around 20 elements. The problem is that i am doing this a great number of times, so any speedup would be very valuable. I think I might look into converting just this logic to C/C++.

Comment: The solution I suggested is `O(n)`, `n` being len(C), and yours is `O(N**2)`.  The extra overhead in my solution is due to the fact it creates another copy of the data (by calling `my_groupby`), which probably cancels out the improved complexity, for n ~ 10000.